# Process/ Work Flow Engine

Tags: workflow, jbpm

I am working on a solution for which I need a work flow/process flow engine. My work flow contains some Java based processes(classes) and some Linux Shell scripts. The flow would not be static and the execution of each process depends on the state/outcome of the previous process, and there would be multiple paths and the path would be determined the state of the previous processes.

I tried looking at jBPM, but I do not find a suitable support for invoking shell scripts. Please suggest me a suitable alternative for my requirement.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well you can use jBPM5, it's extremely simple to add support for running shell scripts, we can help you with that. 
Can you elaborate a little bit more on the requirements that you have?
Cheers